# Selecting columns from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I need to retrieve data from 3 separate tables, as I've added an additional table to the database I'm using.

My layout currently looks like this:

```
 _____________       _____________      ___________      ___________
| users       |     |    links    |    |users_links|    | tags      |
|-------------|     |-------------|    |-----------|    |-----------|
| id          |     | id          |    | id        |    | id        |
| name        |     | long_url    |    | link_id   |    | user_id   |
| username    |     | short_url   |    | user_id   |    | link_id   |
| email       |     | user_id     |    | privacy   |    | tag       |
| password    |     | page_title  |    | notes     |    |           |
| created_at  |     | updated_at  |    |           |    |           |
| updated_at  |     | clicks      |    |-----------|    |-----------|
---------------     | page_title  |
                    --------------
```

Previously I collected my data from two tables (which worked fine), but after feeling the need to allow tagging, this required an additional table.

my original query looks like this:

```
    public static function previouslyShortened($username)
    {
            //Gets all related info for the info for member page
            $query = DB::select("select users.id as user_id,
                    links.id,
                    links.long_url,
                    links.short_url,
                    links.updated_at,
                    links.clicks,
                    links.page_title,
                    users_links.privacy,
                    users_links.notes,
                    from users
                    right outer join users_links on users.id = users_links.user_id
                    join links on links.id = users_links.link_id
                    where users.username = '$username'
                    ". (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username == $username ? "" : "and users_links.privacy = 0")
            );

            $result = array('username' => $username, 'links' => $query);
            return $result;
    }
```

I would like to also include `tags.id` and `tags.tag` from the table `tags` within the query and return it as part of the object being created.

I have attempted this by trying to create another right outer join but I get the error:

```
Syntax error or access violation - Not unique table alias.
```

How can I do this?

---

### edit:

My attempt at the fix was requested so here it is:

```
    public static function previouslyShortened($username)
    {
            //Gets all related info for the info for member page
            $query = DB::select("select users.id as user_id,
                    links.id,
                    links.long_url,
                    links.short_url,
                    links.updated_at,
                    links.clicks,
                    links.page_title,
                    users_links.privacy,
                    users_links.notes,
                    tags.id,
                    tags.tag
                    from users
                    right outer join users_links on users.id = users_links.user_id
                    join links on links.id = users_links.link_id
                    right outer join tags.user_id on users_links.id = tags.user_id
                    join tags on users_links.user_id = tags.user_id
                    where users.username = '$username'
                    ". (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username == $username ? "" : "and users_links.privacy = 0")
            );

            $result = array('username' => $username, 'links' => $query);
            return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt at the additional right outer join?

Comment: tags.id  and links.id would both be in your query then...give them different names than 'id' and you should be good.  If not, post the attempt for us

Comment: @TimS I figured it would complicate things further if I had completely wrong code.   I added the attempt in the attempt in the original post now.  Although now I get the error that the tags.user_id doesn't exist in 'base table'.  http://i.gyazo.com/ca4360986101ea0b52697a76b128188f.png

Comment: @Twelfth can I use another right outer join?

Comment: Not sure why you would right outer join...do you understand the differences between outter and inner...and left outer ve right outer?  Right outer will produce one row for every row in the 'right' table in the join...do you really want one row for each tag regardless of if it has a match in your main query?

Comment: @Twelfth Not entirely, earlier today I did find a useful image explaining the differences.  I think I require a union join, I was just trying to repeat what I thought already worked.  Would that be more efficient?

Comment: I usually avoid right joins...simply because it's a left join with the table orders reversed.  Lets say you have table1 join table2.  If you make this an inner join, then only rows in table1 with a match in table 2 is returned.  A left join returns all rows in table1 regardless of a match in table2...if no entry in table2 is found, it just returns null.  A right join is the same thing, except the tables are reversed (table1 right join table2 is the exact same as table2 left join table1).  You will probably want to rethink your existing joins...

Comment: @Twelfth thankfully this is the only function I have so far that has used joins, so it won't be that much work.  I'll use left inner join, thank you for explaining that to me.

Comment: o... left outter or inner...no left inner :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57794/discussion-between-twelfth-and-samayres1992).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove the error you can try the following code

```
public static function previouslyShortened($username)
{
        //Gets all related info for the info for member page
        $query = DB::select("select users.id as user_id,
                links.id,
                links.long_url,
                links.short_url,
                links.updated_at,
                links.clicks,
                links.page_title,
                users_links.privacy,
                users_links.notes,
                tags.id,
                tags.tag
                from users
                left join users_links on users.id = users_links.user_id
                left join links on links.id = users_links.link_id
                left join tags on users.id = tags.user_id
                where users.username = '$username'
                ". (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username == $username ? "" : "and users_links.privacy = 0") . " group by links.id"
        );
        $result = array('username' => $username, 'links' => $query);
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help, this query returns no errors, but it also doesn't return any data.  I tried a var_dump on the return and, nothing comes back.

Comment: @samayres1992 for data you can check the query without where conditions and then try to put conditions to check for data and relationships are correct between rows.

Comment: @dkkumargoyal - his joins are funny and a right outer combined with an inner and then right outer to an inner join....odds are the rows are being eliminated somewhere along that path. He needs to redo his joining starting at users

Comment: @Twelfth I agree, I also have some confusions in the table structure, like user_id in links table along with a user_links relationship table, both link_id and user_id in the tags table etc.. and why joining tags table twice

Comment: @dkkumargoyal To be perfectly honest with you I'm unsure myself, a few months back I was at uni and asked my friend to help, that's what he told me to do, apparently (clearly) it's wrong.

Comment: @Twelfth I'm sure my questions must be getting a tad annoying (apologies), can you recommend how to go about fixing this query please?  Replace the first right outer join with inner join .. and?

Comment: @dkkumargoyal I gave your query a try, it seems to work almost.  It returns my data, but it repeats it many many many times.  Any idea why this would happen?  If you wish to see what I'm referring to: http://litl.it/user/test  wait a little while for it all to load.  (it seems to load a lot)

Comment: @samayres1992 this may be because of multiple tags for a user or link, you might want to add a group by clause "group by links.id"

Comment: @dkkumargoyal do you mind if we discuss this quickly in a chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57794/discussion-between-twelfth-and-samayres1992

Answer (score 1):

From our chat, here is the from statement:

```
from users 
inner users_links on users.id = users_links.user_id 
inner join links on links.id = users_links.link_id 
left join tags as t1 on users_links.id = t1.user_id 
left tags as t2 on users_links.user_id = t2.user_id
```